# Confusing notation about subsets of ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

I've been learning ring theory from explanatory text my professor has written for the class. It contains the following statement:

Given $R$ a commutative ring with $1\neq0$, $J$ an ideal of $R$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ elements of R. The following are equivalent:

- $(a_1,...,a_n)\subseteq J$,
- $a_1,...,a_n$ are elements of $J$.

Only since recently have I started studying ring theory in my university, so my understanding of the notation is poor. My questions are the following:

- If the notation $\subseteq$ denotes a subset, is the statement not trivially true for any ring or group? Why are all these properties of $J$ mentioned?
- If the notation $\subseteq$ denotes a subring, what does the proof of the statement look like?
- If the notation $\subseteq$ does not denote a subset or a subring, what does the notation $\subseteq$ denote so that the statement is meaningful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $(a_1,...,a_n)$ means to you ? I may be wrong here, but I think it is the source of your confusion. $(a_1,...,a_n)$ is the ideal generated by $a_1,...,a_n$ in $R$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I did not know that $(a_1,...,a_n)$ referred to an ideal. So to put it in simple terms, is the statement saying that any combination of elements $a_1,...,a_n$ of an ideal $J$ of the commutative ring $R$ forms another ideal that is a subset of $J$?

Comment: It is saying that, if what you call combination of elements refers to an expression $\lambda_1 a_1 + ... + \lambda_n a_n$ with the $\lambda_i$ being any element in $R$. I feel an ever better way of restating the proposition (and a bit of a generalization too) is : a subset $S$ of $R$ is a subset of an ideal $J$ if and only if $<S>$ (the ideal generated by $S$) is a subset of $J$. Did you study group theory/linear algebra before ? It should be similar to certain results in these areas.

Comment: I've studied some linear algebra and group theory before and the concept you describe is starting to click in my head. Thanks, yet again.

Answer (score 1):

[Question was resolved in comments to the asker's satisfaction.  Just adding this answer so question doesn't show up on lists of unanswered questions. Please don't accept or up-vote this answer.]

Summary: $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ denotes the ideal generated by $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Comment: You can make it community wiki and so the OP can accept it and other users can upvote it too.